# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName

Tags: java, crystal-reports, wildfly-8

I am using 3rd Party Crystal report jars in my project and when i am running it from local eclipse it works fine. However getting below exception in my DEV env.
I am using jboss 8.2.0 in local as well as in DEV env. I have cecore.jar in my WEB-INF/lib folder.

```
02:35:43,201 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ajpWorker task-1) Failed to define class com/crystaldecisions/sdk/exception/internal/SDKLogonExceptionResources in Module "deployment.smareport
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2640) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1501) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1465) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1419) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1419) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1361) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.internal.SDKLogonExceptionResources.getString(SDKLogonExceptionResources.java:36) [cecore-1.0.jar:14.1.2.1121]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.SDKLogonException.getMessage(SDKLogonException.java:82) [cecore-1.0.jar:14.1.2.1121]
at com.crystaldecisions.celib.exception.CEException.getMessage(CEException.java:244) [celib-1.0.jar:14.1.2.1121]
at com.bfm.app.pirptfe.pidb.crystal.CrystalEnterpriseLogonManager.login(CrystalEnterpriseLogonManager.java:166) [classes:]
at com.bfm.app.pirptfe.pidb.server.filter.TranslateCredentialsFilter.doFilter(TranslateCredentialsFilter.java:276) [classes:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName: com/crystaldecisions/sdk/exception/internal/SDKLogonExceptionResources
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:654) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]     
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
... 49 more
```

Comment: What JDK version are you using in Eclipse?

Comment: I am using jdk1.8 and jboss 8.2 in eclipse and same jdk and jboss is available in DEV env.

Comment: Start from checking the compiled byte code version of your library classes. Use command line like `javap -cp TheLibJar.jar -verbose com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.internal.SDKLogonExceptionResources | grep "major"`

Comment: I ran the command line in my WEB-INF/lib and it says major version:50 javap -cp cecore-1.0.jar -verbose com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.internal.SDKLogonExceptionResources | grep "major"
  major version: 50

Comment: This means it was compiled with java compiler of version 1.6 or earlier. Strange... Is there a chance that your JBoss is using older JRE although it refers to JDK libraries of version 1.8?

Comment: No in my eclipse as well as in dev both places I have java 1.8